# PayPal only Checkout, Remove "Proceed To Checkout" option?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, paypal-express, ce-1.9.2.4

Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 (CE)

I have a requirement to make PayPal Express Checkout the only method for purchasing products. I've looked at various configuration settings, but they seem only to disable the whole checkout process, including the Basket functionality.

Can this be achieved programmatically or with some other method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the "Proceed to Checkout" button on the cart page, you can remove them by adding the following to your `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml` file:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <remove name="checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express.top"/>
    <remove name="checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express.bottom"/>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

If you're talking about the button on the product view page, then the modification is:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <remove name="product.info.addtocart.paypal.wrapper"/>
</catalog_product_view>
```